# change any linux user password using c++

Tags: c++, linux

I want to change any Linux user password using C++, any solution would be great.

I need to do it manually, that mean by opening files (Can't use system()):

- /etc/passwd
- /etc/shadow
- /etc/group

Also seems I need to lock these files. Have c code sample for opening .txt file and reading content, but can't read large content, that is problem too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

const char* path = "/tmp/log.txt";

void read_file()
{
    int fd;
    char buf[1000];
    int i;

    fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    flock(fd, LOCK_SH);

    for(i=0; i < 255 ; i++) {
        read(fd, &buf[i], 1);
        usleep(10 * 10);  // 10 ms
       }

    flock(fd, LOCK_UN);
    close(fd);

    printf("reader: %#x: %s\n", getpid(), buf);
    usleep(10 * 10);  // 10 ms
}

void reader()
{
    read_file();
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    setlinebuf(stdout);
    reader();
    return 0;
}
```

In ideal solution it must work like that:

1. Program ask to enter username.
2. Program ask to enter new password.
3. Open necessary file, change password and save file, but not corrupt it.

Can someone explain with which file I need to work to change password and how to open it properly to not hurt the system? How to edit exactly that line where is password?

At the moment i'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.

**EDIT**

I saw in comments that normal user cant access these files. And one comment was to give permissions to every user change any user password. 
So what about if one user have permissions to edit these files and change password to any user. So is it way to safe open and edit system file `shadow`, save and close it. I need to lock it somehow or how I can access it?

[There](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/#more-115) is `shadow` file structure, as all can see there is special hash or crypt for password, so if change it properly and save file, password must change.

My code to get user data using username:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct passwd *p_entry1, *p_entry2;
    char* username;



    cout<<"Insert username: ";
    cin>>username;
    /* Find user data by entered username */
    p_entry1 = getpwnam(username);

    printf("username = %s = %s"
                   " userid = %d group id = %d"
                   " real name = %s directory = %s"
                   " primary shell = %s",
    p_entry1->pw_name, p_entry1->pw_passwd,
            p_entry1->pw_uid, p_entry1->pw_gid,
            p_entry1->pw_gecos, p_entry1->pw_dir,
            p_entry1->pw_shell);

}
```

Comment: Are there not dozens of questions on this site already about how to open a file and read until the end of the file?

Comment: C or C++? Answers may differ wildly between the two, and asking for both might be considered too broad. Also, you should really try to give your question a proper title, which this one isn't. "but can't read large content" - why? what error did you receive?

Comment: I give this title accidentally... And about c or c++, I don't know where it is more easier and will work better.. 

@abelenky i'm sure that there are topics about it, but I need to open system files, so I ask which file I need to use and how to open it properly.

Comment: Didn't you post this _exact question_ a couple hours ago? I remember because it was also tagged C++ **AND** C and asked about the exact same thing. ([Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858854/change-any-linux-user-password-using-c-or-c) for 10K+ users as I can't confirm this.)

Comment: There is already the `passwd` command for doing this, why would you want to do it yourself? In any case, the source for `passwd` is available and free for you to look at.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that the `passwd` command (assuming it is run by a suitably privileged user) cannot?

Comment: Yes I did,  I deleted it and rewrited to explain better what I need.

Comment: if you mean linux command passwd what can type in teminal, that it's not what I need.. I need to do same, but  with c or c++. I have tried system() in c, but I need to make password change manually by opening file, changing hash and saving it.

Comment: Is it not obvious that an operating system would prevent you from doing this?

Comment: @Arc676: You linked to this page.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry. I have trouble going through my own browser history. [Here's the correct link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855569/change-linux-user-password-using-c-c). This time it redirects to the Page not Found page.

Comment: @Arc676: That's the right link, and you're right about it being a duplicate. Since it's deleted, though, we can't do much about that. :(

Comment: I told you that I have made almoust similar topic and then deleted it.. Can you at lest try to help not talk about offtopics there? +-5 comments about topic what was deleted 2 h ago.. And only few with help to solve my question.

Comment: "I need to do same, but with c or c++." - `passwd` is written in C, if that helps. And you cannot do anything "from C" . unless you use an interpreter. Otherwise the code is compiled and the executable is no C anymore, but machine code.

Comment: Ok.. So there are no way to change any linux user password by using c or c++?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is possible in this way -> to make c++ code which change password I done this:

- Password must be encrypted, so I used code to make it in `$6$:SHA-512` hash.
- Must open `/etc/shadow` file, read it, find user by username and change password. [There](http://nixcraft928.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=60099314&item=2) you can read about `shadow` file structure.

To open file used fstream, to find and change line I used `std::getline` and `std::vector`.

To run .cpp file, need to be root in terminal, run `g++ fileName.cpp -o excqFileName -lcrypt` and `./excqFileName` commands. Thats it's for me.

That all folks, I did my task and it's possible. Will not share code, but I explained enough to understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

To change a user's password you may use the **[putpwent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putpwent.3.html)** and **[putspent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putspent.3.html)** functions from `<pwd.h>` and `<shadow.h>` respectively. This way you don't need to explicitly read, parse, and write the passwd and shadow files.

**Regarding permissions:**

If you're not willing to run your program as root, an alternative is to give **[setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)** permission to your executable file, just like the `passwd` executable itself.

```
chown root.root <executable>
chmod u+s <executable>
```

A `setuid` program is executed under the privileges/permissions of its owner (in this case `root`), so you're granted the binary owner's privileges/permissions.

If your binary is owned by `root` and it has the `suid` permission, it will be able to change `/etc/passwd` and any other files that only `root` has access to. This is quite handy, but at the same time it can be quite dangerous. For instance, if your program has a bug or unforeseen circumstance, it may be exploited by a malicious user to gain root privilege/access in your system.

Writing secure programs seem to be simple, but it has various gotchas. Good luck!

Comment: I think about it, but person who give me that task said that we will have one user with permission who can access system files. So now anyway I can't use `system()`. My main task is open and change password in `shadow` file using right hash for password.  Shadow file structure, also shown how look user line (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/#more-115) sry for link, don't know how to make link right

Comment: @RinaldsGudriks did update my answer to suggest how to change the password using specific functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you make simple please? Would be very nice to see at least some examples, because I haven't seen any.. 
Also I have question, better try to make program in C or C++ then?

Comment: @RinaldsGudriks sorry, I can't write 30+ lines for you right now, [but this hopefully helps](http://linux.omnipotent.net/article.php?article_id=10935). It explains in details how the password management works. Alternatively, Google and GitHub can help you with more examples.

Comment: I have read that article already, have code when I write username and get back user data (name,id,password(not shown),home dir etc.). But there is no code when he writes something in shadow file or change password.. Only get data in console or write .db file.

Comment: He writes code in C right? Can I write something similar in C++. I don't understand how to use build in function, maybe it's easy, but i'm newbie in this and realy need some working example... Not full, at least to understand what and how it all must work. I will also edit article and show my code, mby you could suggest if I can use it. Can you at least steps what and how I need to do to get something work?

Comment: A C++ compiler is able to compile C code (with a few caveats). You don't need to rewrite it in C++. If you're a beginner, I'd suggest you to start with something simpler, and study some concepts used by the language and the compiler (functions, headers, libraries, linker, etc).

Comment: I have task, I need to do it somehow.. I can use any suggestions, but I must do it. I have some time for this task, I know C++ basics, but It's my first time working with system and system files. So that why I ask there for help and wise suggestions. But still would be great to have some samples, I understand that you don't have time.. Maybe you could make some little samples, or some peace code just to understand how work `putpwent` and `putspent`, not now, mby tomorow.. Please, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @RinaldsGudriks Did you check [the link](http://linux.omnipotent.net/article.php?article_id=10935) I suggested in a previous comment? It has an example using `putpwent`.

Comment: Ohh yes, right, he change username and putted it intro db.. Same I can change username/password and put it to `shadow` file?

Comment: @RinaldsGudriks: [working example](https://github.com/rdebath/SLS-1.02/blob/52b227abe5276e4bdba1c09319c3a4c3c5450079/usr/src/admutil/passwd.c) (license is GPL and the code is quite old).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access these files directly, of course, because they're privileged files that are owned by root. After all, there wouldn't be much security if any process can randomly scribble over these files, and change anyone's password.

As such, there is no way to avoid privilege escalation in order to update a system password. This is a basic, fundamental security principle.

So, no matter how you go about it, at some point, something, somewhere, has to `system()`-execute a privileged binary. There is a reason why `/usr/bin/passwd` is a setuid-root binary.

So, if you can't use `system()`, you cannot do it. This is fundamental.

The most that can could possibly be done here is to have a separate daemon process running, as root, and have your application connect and communicate with it, passing the appropriate credentials to it, and have the daemon process take care of changing the password. This would avoid having to use `system()` directly, by the application.

As far as the task of actually changing the password, once you have sufficient root privileges to do it, this is not typically done by scribbling over the files yourself. The [Linux PAM library](http://www.linux-pam.org/) provides an API for verifying and updating system passwords. Consult the Linux PAM library documentation for more information.

Comment: So you want to say that it's impossible to just open necessary file and change user password?

Comment: Right. Try to open the file yourself, for writing, as a regular user. You can't. It's read-only. Linux security 101.

Comment: I can't unlock them somehow, to edit and then lock back?

Comment: Try to think logically. Linux is a sophisticated, multi-user operating system. Multiple users can be using the same Linux system, with the operating system responsible for security, and preventing each user from messing up all other users. If this would be possible, that means that another user can do the same, and change your password, since they'll be able to write anything to `/etc/passwd`, themselves.

Comment: Ok... Even if try to do it with `system()`, I have tryed it.. Still I can't change any users password only by typing `system("passwd username")`, because only root can do this, but `system("sudo passwd username")` makes other error.

Comment: You can't seriously expect to circumvent system security and bypass basic user privilege restrictions just by writing your own C program?

Comment: I'm searching for solution for task what I have.. I need to change any user password using c or c++ program. 

So even if use system() I don't know how to access commands as root and if it's even possible.

Comment: If you run your program as root, then it should be able to run privileged commands.

Comment: you mean if I run file from terminal?

Also I have question: So if one of the users have permission to access system files, then it is possible to open them, rewrite and then make safe save?

Comment: @Sam if executable is owned by root and has setuid permissions, it can definitely open and modify /etc/passwd AFAIK

Comment: I'm almost sure that to change password need to change and modify `shadow` file... But I think that if I have my program in folder with root permission I could run system("sudo passwd username"), but I can't do it.. Task is do it manually with user who have permissions.